# Why the integral of the transformed probability density function is not equal to 1.

Tags: integration, random-variables, transformation

Hello everyone There was a question when solving the task. I have been given a random variable whose probability density function obeys the normal distribution law with parameters m = 2, d = 1.5. This is how [my function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oUGQ.png) looks like. I am also given a conversion function $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$. According to the assignment, I need to find the distribution function and the probability density function and the distribution function of the transformed random variable. I kind of found [this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGnyK.png) using [the functional transformation of random variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDcMS.png), but I am haunted by the fact that its integral is [not equal to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilyyQ.png), but is equal to 0.949. So my distribution function is [not equal to 1 at infinity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC1Jf.png). Help me figure it out, please. Thank you all!

Comment: If your original distribution on $x$ is normal, that means that $x$ is sometimes negative. What happens to $g(x)= \sqrt{x}$ when $x$ is negative?

Comment: I notice that 0.949 is the same value you get from integrating your original normal distribution from $0$ to $\infty$. This tells me that you're failing to take into account values of $x$ less than $0$. Are you sure it's not $g(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$?

Comment: oh, of course, thank you very much. How such a simple explanation did not reach me is not clear. It turns out that the problem has no solution with a probability of 0.051? And the mathematical moments of the transformed distribution cannot be found, such as mathematical expectation and variance?

Comment: I think the answer is simply that the transformed distribution is not defined.

Comment: Okay, I get it. If you write it down as an answer, I will mark it as a solution (I may not do it right away)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original distribution on $x$ is normal, which means that $x$ can be negative. Since $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$ doesn't yield a real number when $x<0$, the transformed distribution is undefined.

I also notice that the number you get as the integral of your transformed distribution, 0.949, is the same value you get when integrating your original normal distribution from $0$ to $\infty$. This underlines the fact that you're not taking into account values of $x$ less than $0$.